# No results matched the query

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm not sure if this is a matter of the IBAction below the didReceiveMemoryWarning not calling the same variables as the query below viewDidLoad method, or some other issue.  But when I run this code, I get an error that says "no results matched the query" and "the operation couldn't be completed. Parse error 101."  Could anyone tell me why that is?

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var voteCount1 = PFObject(className: "VoteCount")
    voteCount1["choices"] = 2
    voteCount1["votes"] = Int()
    voteCount1["votes2"] = Int()
    voteCount1["optionName"] = String()
    voteCount1["optionName2"] = String()
    voteCount1["objectId"] = String()

    var voteCount2 = PFObject(className: "VoteCount2")
    voteCount2["choices"] = 3
    voteCount2["votes"] = Int()
    voteCount2["votes2"] = Int()
    voteCount2["votes3"] = Int()
    voteCount2["optionName"] = String()
    voteCount2["optionName2"] = String()
    voteCount2["optionName3"] = String()

    var voteCount3 = PFObject(className: "VoteCount3")
    voteCount3["choices"] = 4
    voteCount3["votes"] = Int()
    voteCount3["votes2"] = Int()
    voteCount3["votes3"] = Int()
    voteCount3["votes4"] = Int()
    voteCount3["optionName"] = String()
    voteCount3["optionName2"] = String()
    voteCount3["optionName3"] = String()
    voteCount3["optionName4"] = String()

    var query = PFQuery(className: "VoteCount")
    query.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (count: Int32, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            let randNumber = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count))
            query.whereKey("voteNumber", equalTo: NSNumber(unsignedInt:randNumber))
            query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (voteCount1: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    NSLog("%@", error)
                } else {
                    let votes = voteCount1["votes"] as Int
                    let votes2 = voteCount1["votes2"] as Int
                    let option1 = voteCount1["optionName"] as String
                    let option2 = voteCount1["optionName2"] as String
                    self.showOption1.text = "\(option1)"
                    self.showOption2.text = "\(option2)"
                }

            }
        } else {
            println("error \(error)")
        }
        }


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}




@IBOutlet weak var pollResults: UILabel!

@IBAction func addVote1(sender: AnyObject) {
    var query = PFQuery(className: "VoteCount")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("objectId") {
        (voteCount1: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            NSLog("%@", error)
        } else {
            voteCount1.incrementKey("votes")
            voteCount1.saveInBackgroundWithTarget(nil, selector: nil)
            let votes = voteCount1["votes"] as Int
            let votes2 = voteCount1["votes2"] as Int
            self.pollResults.text = "\(votes)   \(votes2)"
        }
        }
}

@IBOutlet weak var pollResults2: UILabel!

@IBAction func addVote2(sender: AnyObject) {
    var query = PFQuery(className: "VoteCount")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("objectId") {
        (voteCount1: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            NSLog("%@", error)
        } else {
            voteCount1.incrementKey("votes2")
            voteCount1.saveInBackgroundWithTarget(nil, selector: nil)
            let votes = voteCount1["votes"] as Int
            let votes2 = voteCount1["votes2"] as Int
            self.pollResults2.text = "\(votes)   \(votes2)"
        }
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is call the values for the variables "votes" "votes2" "option1" and "option2" from a random row on my Parse database.  I've created a column of Int data called "voteNumber" that each contains a number 1 to 1000 and I believe by calling a row with a random number I should be able to call all the appropriate data from a random row.  I'm just not sure if I'm bridging the query within the viewDidLoad method with the IBActions underneath the closing of the didReceiveMemoryWarning method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the definition, `equalTo:` expects an `id` which translates to `AnyObject` in Swift.  In both Swift and Objective-C you would need to convert the number to a `NSNumber` object to get the code to work.

#### Approach 1: Manual conversion

The first approach is to simply create a new `NSNumber` wrapping the value:

Objective-C:

```
// Option 1:
[query whereKey:@"voteNumber" equalTo: @(randNumber)];

// Option 2:
[query whereKey:@"voteNumber" equalTo: [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:randNumber]];
```

Swift:

```
query.whereKey("voteNumber", equalTo: NSNumber(unsignedInt:randNumber))
```

#### Approach 2: Objective-C bridging

Certain types in Swift qualify for [automatic bridging](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-XID_45) to Objective-C types.  While `UInt32` doesn't qualify, it can safely upcast to `UInt` which does:

```
let randNumber = UInt(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count)))
query.whereKey("voteNumber", equalTo: randNumber)
```

Comment: I really appreciate the reply.  Is it not possible to have the queries both within and outside the didReceiveMemoryWarning method to call and update data from the same source?  I just updated my question above.

Comment: @hamzawesome You should post that as a new question. It's completely different from the original question.

Comment: I can't, I was blocked from posting any more questions for a month, so this is my only option lol. Granted this is what I've updated my code to.

Comment: @hamzawesome Changing your question after accepting an answer isn't going to help any.  It dilutes the value of the site and makes people less likely to answer your questions.  Instead read [this post on how to get unblocked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).